# Array deducting 1 from previous element when repeated more than once

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following array:

Input:

```
array = [211, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200]
```

Ouput:

```
array = [211, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196 ... ]
```

I've tried `each_with_index` but couldn't get the desired result.

Comment: The algorithm is not clear - what are expecting? an array starting with nil, and then consecutive numbers in descending order starting from 211?

Comment: that's it, I removed the nil, probably confusing.

Comment: so you want a list of numbers in descending order starting from 211? what does it have to do with duplicates?

Comment: I want the values in the array to be replaced in that order

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it - what will be the expected output for `[10, 8, 5, 5, 7]`?

Comment: that would work as well, then it can go [211, 199, 198, 197...]

Comment: its already in decsending order so [10, 8, 5, 5, 7] would be `[10, 8, 7, 5, 5]` and then I would like it to be `[10, 8, 7, 5, 4]`

Comment: You should add more detail to your example and explain the transformation of input to output.

Comment: Why wouldn't you have [211, 199, 198, 197, 196 ...] instead of [211, 210, 210, 209] ?

Comment: that would work too, I made some edit, should be a little less confusing now.

Comment: The confusion is entirely related to your use of the term, "duplicates". All the elements of `[3,3,3]` may be regarded as duplicates, in the sense that none is unique. I would get rid of that word and say something like, "if an element of `array` is equal to another element of `array` with a lower index...`.

Comment: I agree, the title is misleading, edited

Comment: I don't think your edit is sufficient, for two reasons. Firsly, many readers just skim titles, not expecting them to contain crucial information. You should always write the question so that it's clear without reference to the title. Secondly, even if one reads your edited title carefully, it's still not clear. You need to state in the body of the question precisely what you want. Having an example with expected output is great, and is sometimes sufficient, but not here. If your original title referred to "duplicates", that would be fine, provided that is made precise in the question.

Comment: So what about `[10, 9, 9, 8]`? Would that become `[10, 9, 8, 8]`?

Comment: @Ajedi32, that was my assumption (added your array to the examples in my answer), but we'll see if Luke confirms that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, I noticed that behavior in the last example of your answer which is why I asked. My interpretation of the problem was somewhat different, which is why I named the method in my answer `force_descending`, implying that the goal is to end up with an array where each successive element is less than the preceding one. No idea whether or not that's really the case.

Comment: How did you decide to stop at 12 x 200's? Did you fall asleep?

Comment: @7stud, are you suggesting that it should have been `array = [211, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196 zzzzzzzzzzz ]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what are to be done with `nil`s, so I haven't addressed that. Let `arr` be `array` or `array.sort.reverse`, depending on requirements. I think this is want you want to do? (See my comment on the question.)

```
def change_em(arr)
  dup_indices = arr.each_index
                   .group_by { |i| arr[i] }
                   .values
                   .flat_map { |a| a.drop(1) }
  puts "dup_indices = #{dup_indices}"
  last = 0 # anything '-' responds to
  arr.each_index.map { |i| last = dup_indices.include?(i) ? last-1 : arr[i] }
end
```

I've included the `puts` just to clarify what I'm doing here.

```
change_em [10, 8, 5, 5, 7]
  #=> dup_indices = [3]
  #=> [10, 8, 5, 4, 7]
change_em [10, 8, 7, 5, 5]
  #=> dup_indices = [4]
  #=> [10, 8, 7, 5, 4]
change_em [10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8]
  #=> dup_indices = [2, 4, 5]
  #=> [10, 9, 8, 8, 7, 6]
change_em [211, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 196]
  #=> dup_indices = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] 
  #=> [211, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 190, 196]
```

Notice that the statement

```
last = dup_indices.include?(i) ? last-1 : arr[i]
```

is doing [double-duty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double-duty): it updates the value of `last` and returns the mapped value for the index `i`. Note also that `dup_indices` cannot contain `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this is a more functional style.

```
def f(arr, dup_element = nil, dup_count = 0)
  return generate_dup_array(dup_element, dup_count) if arr.empty?
  if arr.head != arr.tail.head # Not duplicates
    if dup_count == 0 # No duplicates to insert
      [arr.head] + f(arr.tail)
    else # There are duplicates to insert 
      generate_dup_array(dup_element, dup_count) + f(arr.tail)
    end
  else # Duplicate found, continue with tail of array and increase dup_count
    f(arr.tail, arr.head, dup_count + 1)
  end
end

def generate_dup_array(dup_element, dup_count)
  return [] if dup_count == 0
  (dup_element - dup_count..dup_element).to_a.reverse
end

class Array
  def head; self.first; end
  def tail; self[1..-1]; end
end

p f [211, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200]
# => [211, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 190]

p f [10, 8, 5, 5, 7].sort.reverse
# => [10, 8, 7, 5, 4]

p f [9, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]
# => [9, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your requirements, but here's my attempt:

```
# Transforms an array of numbers into a sorted array of the same length, where
# each successive element is always smaller than the preceding element.
def force_descending(array)
  array.sort.reverse.each_with_object([]) do |element, collection|
    collection << if collection.empty? || element < collection.last
      element
    else
     collection.last-1
    end
  end
end
```

Sample inputs/outputs:

```
force_descending [211, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200]
#=> [211, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 190]

force_descending [10, 8, 5, 5, 7]
#=> [10, 8, 7, 5, 4]

force_descending [211, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 196]
#=> [211, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 190, 189]
```

Answer (score 0):

> its already in decsending order

For the one-liner crowd:

```
results = numbers.chunk {|num| num}.flat_map {|num, group| (group.length == 1) ? num : ((num - (group.length-1))..num).to_a.reverse}
```

For sane programmers:

```
numbers = [211, 200, 200, 200]
start_of_dups = "_START_"  #Something not in the array
dup_count = 0

results = numbers.map do |num|
  if start_of_dups == num
    dup_count += 1
    num - dup_count
  else
    dup_count = 0 
    start_of_dups = num
  end
end

p results

--output:--
[211, 200, 199, 198]
```

But if:

```
array = [10, 10, 10, 9]

--output:--
[10, 9, 8, 9]
```